# How do I find the current through a motor caused by a PWM signal?

Tags: current, motor, pwm

To investigate the effects of changing the PWM frequency and inductance from a motor I want to model the current flowing through it.

First I calculate how the voltage signal going through the motor phase will look like. So far so good:
[image: PWM signal]

Now I want to find out what the current is caused by this voltage signal. For the motor I'm using the following is true:

$$U = R \cdot I + L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt} +\frac{RPM}{k_V}$$

There are two different situations:
PWM signal is high
$$U_{supply} -  k_V \cdot RPM = R \cdot I + L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt}$$
PWM signal is low:
$$-  \frac{RPM}{k_V} = R \cdot I + L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Both equations have the same homogenous solution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R \cdot I + L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt} &= 0\\
L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt} & = -R \cdot I \\
\int L \cdot \frac{1}{I}\cdot dI &= - \int R \cdot dt \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

By intergrating on both sides I get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L \cdot \log(I) + K_2 &= -R \cdot t + K_1 \\
\log(I)&= -\frac{R}{L} \cdot t + K_3 \\
I&= e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t + K_3 }\\
I&= K \cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The derivative is:
$$ \frac{dI}{dt}= -\frac{R\cdot K}{L}\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t} $$

I think I did something wrong in one of these steps since if I fill this in the situation of PWM being low I find:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-  \frac{RPM}{k_V} &= R \cdot I + L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt}\\
- \frac{RPM}{k_V} &= R \cdot K \cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t} - L \cdot \frac{R\cdot K}{L}\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t}\\
- \frac{RPM}{k_V} &= R \cdot K \cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t} - R\cdot K\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L} \cdot t}\\
- \frac{RPM}{k_V} &= 0\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This is simply not true, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What type of motor is it?

Comment: How have you dealt with initial conditions?

Comment: @Chu A 3 phase BLDC motor, And about the initial conditions I think it should be I(t=0) = 0. Than I find K = 0, so the current would always be 0. So that is not really helping either.

Comment: But the initial condition changes with every PWM transition. It can't be considered as a series of step inputs unless the PWM frequency is very low.

Comment: Aah okay, any ideas how I should do it than, or where I can find how to do it?

Comment: Your equations have assumed that the input voltage is zero (Usupply disappears after the second equation)' so of course there will be zero velocity, because there's zero voltage. The homogeneous equation alone is not sufficient.

Comment: I think you're attempting to predict the response to a PWM bit-by-bit. Then at each transition you have to know what the current and velocity values are and use these as the initial conditions in the differential equation. So every transition needs the velocity and current values prevailing at the end of the response to the preceding transition. Because PWM is not composed of equal duration pulses, the response at every individual transition must be evaluated.

Comment: @Chu Thanks a lot, I think you are right. I will try to give each interval its own initial conditions.